# Objective c - transparent draw on view (UIVisualEffectView)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to create a transparent draw on a view (like the red draw inside the yellow view).
I have some view (`UIVisualEffectView` - the yellow view) and i want to draw with the finger, and it will looks like we "erase" it.

I created a subclass of `UIVisualEffectView` and tried to draw, but its not working so well..

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for (UITouch *touch in touches)
    {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self];
        CGFloat drawSize = 45;
        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(location.x, location.y, drawSize, drawSize);
        [self test:rect];
    }
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for (UITouch *touch in touches)
    {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self];
        CGFloat drawSize = 45;
        [self test:CGRectMake(location.x, location.y, drawSize, drawSize)];
    }
}

-(void)test:(CGRect)rect
{
    if (!self.mask)
    {
        self.mask = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.bounds];
        self.mask.clipsToBounds = YES;
        self.mask.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }

    if (!self.fillLayer)
    {
        self.fillLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        self.fillLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd;
        self.fillLayer.fillColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
    }

    if (!self.outerbezierPath)
    {
        self.outerbezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bounds cornerRadius:0];
        self.outerbezierPath.usesEvenOddFillRule = NO;
    }

    self.innerCirclepath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rect cornerRadius:rect.size.height * 0.5];


    [self.outerbezierPath appendPath:self.innerCirclepath];

    [self.fillLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
    self.fillLayer.path = self.outerbezierPath.CGPath;

    [self.mask.layer addSublayer:self.fillLayer];
    self.maskView = self.mask;
}
```

Comment: What is the result? What is not working?

Comment: Instead smooth line i get lots of circles in the path i draw.